# SvelteKit + Vercel : error 500 when opening web site, config?

Tags: node.js, npm, svelte, vercel, sveltekit

i'm using vercel + svelte kit to learn, and i have a problem after deploying when i go to my site :
500: INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR
I have checked the log and the problem come from :

```
ERROR   WARNING: NODE_ENV value of 'production' did not match any deployment config file names.<br>
ERROR   WARNING: See https://github.com/lorenwest/node-config/wiki/Strict-Mode<br>
ERROR   WARNING: No configurations found in configuration directory:/var/task/config<br>
ERROR   WARNING: To disable this warning set SUPPRESS_NO_CONFIG_WARNING in the environment.<br>
ERROR   Error: Configuration property "mongoURI" is not defined
```

So it seems that mongoURI which should be get from config (Npm config)
can't find the production.json (or default.json) located into the "config" directory

However, when i check the building log on vercel (deployement)
i don't have this error, and i can even console.log(mongoURI)
what i am missing ?